# Objects Too Big To Care About?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, set-theory

I was wondering if in certain fields of math (denoted by some set of axioms describing some class of objects), that there is a cap on size beyond which the existence of larger objects is "irrelevant" in a formal sense. That is, the larger objects (if they exist) can be formed trivially from the smaller objects in a way that does not add any more "essential" structure besides increased cardinality.

Comment: Peano Arithmetic (PA) has proof theoretic ordinal $\varepsilon_0$. That means that functions that at least as fast as $H_{\varepsilon_0}$, H being the Hardy hierarchy, are not provably recursive. So for example, the Goodstein function $G(x)$ is not provably recursive in PA. While the function $G(G(x))$ certainly grows faster, it is still not provably recursive in PA. I am totally not sure whether this answers your question, but it is at least relevant so I posted it as a comment.

Comment: I'm also not sure whether this answers your question, but it brings to mind Kuratowski's Theorem and Wagner's Theorem, which both show the non-planar graphs always "contain" in some loose sense $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. So, no matter the complexity, or lack thereof, of larger non-planar graphs, the non-planarity can always be traced back to those two graphs.

Comment: @TheoBendit: I don't think that this is related to the question. Certainly we care about non-planar graphs. And they are not built up out of $K_5$s or $K_{3,3}$s; they just contain at least one copy of them.

Comment: Downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem implies that every model of certain theory is an elementary extension of a countable model, so in certain sense every model can be constructed from a countable model by adjoining objects which don't change truth of any sentence. I must admit though that in no way this adjoining is trivial, and one could argue whether we add any "essential" structure.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Point taken, but I think you'd struggle to find any example in mathematics of "things" made of basic building blocks where the "things" are of no interest whatsoever. The point I was making was that non-planarity essentially reduces to two cases, so if you're specifically questioning what makes a graph planar, it turns out you need to only examine two cases.

Comment: @Wojowu, but that's all first-order stuff. The moment you go to second-order logic, which is what 99% of mathematicians care about, the higher cardinalities become essential.

Comment: @goblin Of course you are right. I just thought that first-order (I should've pointed that out) theories would serve a good example.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the study of [*separable metric spaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space#Cardinality) a valid field, that provides an example (although by the wrong reason): They have cardinality bounded by that of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This example is not quite right, since as you point out the cardinality of separable metric spaces is at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ (which is a constant, within a fixed mathematical universe). So you can't quite form larger objects from smaller ones, since there is no separable metric space of size $(2^{\aleph_0})^+$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The OP said "if they exist". Nevertheless, do you think I should post this as a comment, or simply delete it?